# Can you tell me why no file is uploaded, I only get the filename i the tabel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Can you tell me why no file is uploaded, I only get the filename i the tabel ?

I dont get any errors message, all information is loaded okay in DB ?

I'am using LINQ to SQL MVC4

Table  id - CompanyNameCon  -  PdfCon

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(DAT_SupplyCon DAT_SupplyCon, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        DAT_SupplyCon.PdfCon = FileUpload.UploadFile(file);

        db.DAT_SupplyCons.InsertOnSubmit(DAT_SupplyCon);
        db.SubmitChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(DAT_SupplyCon);
}
```

view

```
@model CFire2.Models.DAT_SupplyCon

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>



@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "DAT_SupplyCons", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype          = "multipart/form-data" }))
{    
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
<legend>DAT_SupplyCon</legend>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SupplierCon)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SupplierCon)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SupplierCon)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyNameCon)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CompanyNameCon)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyNameCon)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PdfCon)

</div>
<div class="editor-field">
<input type="file" name="file" />
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PdfCon)
</div>


<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Utils:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;


namespace CFire2.Utils
{
public static class FileUpload
{

public static char DirSeparator =
System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
public static string FilesPath = "Content" +
DirSeparator + "Uploads" + DirSeparator;
public static string UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{

   if (null == file) return "";

   if (!(file.ContentLength > 0)) return "";
   string fileName = file.FileName;
   string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);


   if (null == fileExt) return "";

   if (!Directory.Exists(FilesPath))
   {

      Directory.CreateDirectory(FilesPath);
   }

   string path = FilesPath + DirSeparator + fileName;

   file.SaveAs(Path.GetFullPath(path));

   return fileName;
}
public static void DeleteFile(string fileName)
{

   if (fileName.Length == 0) return;

   string path = FilesPath + DirSeparator + fileName;

   if (File.Exists(Path.GetFullPath(path)))
   {

       File.Delete(Path.GetFullPath(path));
   }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `Server.MapPath` is the solution. Example:

```
var path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content"), fileName);  
file.SaveAs(path);
```

Comment: Hi Marthin I get a error " name server does not exist in the current context", if I change to Microsoft.sql.server, the same error comes with" MapPath. Can you show me, how you would use it ?

Comment: In a controller you can directly access the `Server` property, but in another class you need to get it from the current `HttpContext`. I modified my answer to show it.

Comment: Hi Marthijn, tks. for your help, it Works :-)    Can you suggest how I can make a view with a list from the DB, able to open the file

Comment: You have to store the filenames in the table together with some other properties you want (e.g. `SupplierCon`). Then query all the entries from the database and in the view you can create links to the files the same way as the `path` variable above.

Comment: Hi Marthijn  Tks a lot, I appreciate your time and help